# Spectral Python imshow displaying scrambled image

Tags: spectral-python

I am learning Spectral Python and using [their own documentation](https://www.spectralpython.net/graphics.html) and sample image files to display a multispectral image as RGB. However, for some reason, my image appears scrambled up. I have tested the image file by opening it in MultiSpec and it appears as it should, so I do not think the file is damaged. My code is as follows:

```
import spectral as s
import matplotlib as mpl

path = '/content/92AV3C.lan'

img = s.open_image(path)

print(img)

#Load and display hyperspectral image
arr = img.load()
view = s.imshow(arr, (29, 19, 9))
print(view)

#Load and display Ground truth image
gt = s.open_image('92AV3GT.GIS').read_band(0)
view = s.imshow(classes=gt)
```

Output is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try the following command instead of  view=imshow(img, (RGB))`.  SpectralPython has the smarts, once you identify the image type, i.e., *.lan to display the image in the correct format.